# Find missing rows in number range in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, math, pdo, sql-server-2014

I am using PHP to access a SQL server database and I have 2 numbers stored as PHP variables.

For example one variable is `10` and the other variable is `15`.

I need to output a list of 'missing' documents i.e rows where a certain column `col1` does not contain numbers between `10` and `15`.

Is it possible to do this in SQL i.e. something like `... WHERE col1 NOT IN (10..15)`?

Example:

```
col1
----
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Variables:

```
$start = 10
$end = 15
```

Desired result using SQL only:

```
result
------
11
13
15
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: WHERE col1  < 10 or col1 > 15

Comment: `BETWEEN`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP and variables have you defined them as variables?

Where are you getting the variables from? For example if you are submitting a form you need to output that information:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="search1">
<input type="text" name="search2">
```

...etc.

Then you can on your php define this as:

```
$var1 = $_POST['search1'];
$var2 = $_POST['search2'];
```

Then in your MySQL statement (as above answer would work)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE col1 NOT IN ('%".$search1."%', '%".$search2."%')
```

I hope that helps in any case. Your question was a little vague so thought I'd try and cover a couple of bases.